# Pressing a button doesn't load gui

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

**Problem:**
So I am programming an app using a custom font, and I coded it so when you press a button the font will load. When you press the button that says "Press me to load after 15 seconds!" a user input box should appear along with some empty posts, some text and another button (that doesn't do anything yet) but nothing shows up. I don't get any errors. I would like help figuring out why nothing is showing up and how I can get the proper stuff to render.

**How it works:**
When you press the button "press me to load the app after 15 seconds!" the variable fontLoaded should change to true (I don't know if it actually changes), and then that would cause the code to render everything else to start. Nothing renders.

**What else have I tried:**
I've tried the other method where you put the variable fontLoaded after the code that loads the font so it's automatic, and that doesn't do anything either. I haven't tried anything else, because I don't know what else to try.

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';

var fontLoaded = false;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        'Cabin-Regular-TTF': require('./Cabin-Regular-TTF.ttf'),
      });
 }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { postInput: ""}
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
            title="Press Me To Load the App After 15 Seconds!"
            color="#fe8200"
            accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
          />
        </View>


        {fontLoaded ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Whats on your mind? Create a post!
            </Text>  

            <TextInput>
                style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
                value={this.state.postInput}    
            </TextInput>

        <Button
                title="+"
                color="#fe8200"
                accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
            />

            <ScrollView>
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
             </ScrollView>
          </View>) : (null) }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `this.state.fontLoaded` in the return of the render method, you are using the global variable `fontLoaded` which did not change. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused about where to put it. Can you give me an example of the line of code I have to change? Thank you!

Comment: `{fontLoaded ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>` ....

Change this variable `fontLoaded` to `this.state.fontLoaded`

Comment: Great anytime!!